# AngularJS - My chart doesn't show the legend, doesn't start in zero, and doesn't change the color

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, charts

I'm having a problem that my chart only start with the lowest value so I can't see it and my legend doesn't appear.
And I'm trying to change de default colors, but no matter what I do, nothing changes.

HTML:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-chart.css"/>
<script src="http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

....

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="fc.data"
                      chart-labels="fc.labels" colours="colours" chart-series="fc.series" chart-legend="true">
    </canvas> 
</div>
```

Angular:

```
app.controller('lhistorico', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.colours = [{
        fillColor: '#46BFBD',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
        highlightFill: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
        highlightStroke: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)'
    }];

    $http.get('/servico/faberto/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.faturas = angular.fromJson(data);
    });

    $http.get('/servico/historico/').success(function(data){
        $scope.fc = angular.fromJson(data);         
    });

    $http.get('/servico/lhist/').success(function(data){
        $scope.lhist = angular.fromJson(data);          
    });


});
```

NodeJS/Express:

```
app.get('/servico/historico/',function(req,res){
connection = createConnection();    
var queryString = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fatDataVenc, '%d/%l/%Y') AS     venc,fatValor FROM faturas WHERE  ff_empID = '"+ req.cookies.login.fu_empID +"'GROUP BY venc ORDER BY venc DESC LIMIT 12";
connection.query(queryString,function(err,rows){        
    var fc = {
        series : ["Valor"],
        labels : [],
        data: []
    };

    if(rows.length>0){
        for(var i = 0;i<rows.length;i++){                
            fc.labels.push(rows[i].venc);
            fc.data.push(rows[i].fatValor);
        }
    }else{
        fc.labels = "";
        fc.data = [0];
    }

    return res.json(fc);
});
connection.end();    
});
```

Comment: create a bootply or jsfiddle that might help.

Comment: Regarding the data if it's not displaying correctly: try placing data array in another array so it looks something like this: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, prior to returning it to Angular. I'm using `angular-chart` and I had to do it this way, too. Also, you should really look at some examples at angular-chart website, see how to set colors. You need to use this format: `$scope.barColors = ['#ED6A5A','#7AC18D','#5CA4A9','#2D2D2D'];` and for labels `$scope.barLabels = ['label1', 'label2'];`
Angular-chart works different than vanilla Chart.js, look at the docs and examples.